# Get COUNT() of rows where first 3 digits of column are alike

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a result set of codes that are usually three digits followed by up to 2 digits like `012.34` or `123.45`. The first three digits define a general category of group, and the digits following the decimal place define more specific qualities. There could be 77 `012.xx` numbers, and there are hundreds of unique 3 digit group definitions, followed by a varying number of digits per entry.

Does anyone know how to write a quick query to achieve this?

Comment: You could use PARSENAME to get the individual pieces. It would be FAR better if you could normalize your structures instead of putting 2 values in a single column.

Comment: Agreed, not a great way to store your data.

Comment: Agreed, unfortunately the data is regulated/structured by an external organization. We just make use of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it is in a `varchar` column since you're storing `012.34`...

```
SELECT LEFT(someColumn,3), COUNT(*)
FROM someTable
GROUP BY LEFT(someColumn,3)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5 -- per your comments
ORDER BY LEFT(someColumn,3)
```

If it's not, then you'd do this:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),someColumn),3), COUNT(*)
FROM someTable
GROUP BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),someColumn),3)
ORDER BY LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),someColumn),3)
```

Comment: Giving both options a go, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Is there any chance you know how to filter by COUNTs larger than 'X'?

Comment: after the `GROUP BY`, add `HAVING COUNT(*) > 5`, see above.

Comment: As soon as time limit on accepting answer goes away, I'll mark as correct. Thanks @JiggsJedi!

Comment: This would be better assuming the first part is a fixed length.

Comment: I read the question that only the second part is variable length, but I suppose you could read it either way -- @rypress if that's the case, this is not a good answer... this only works if the numbers left of the `.` is always a length of 3.

Comment: The first part is in fact only ever 3 digits, so you - by chance - nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

it depends if your resultset is numeric or characters. if not numeric you can use string operations.

```
 select left(resultSet,charindex('.',resultset)) , count(*)
   from x 
     group by by left(resultSet,charindex('.',resultset))
     order by left(resultSet,charindex('.',resultset))
```

with charindex you will get a correct 'cut' when the first digits are not 3 as 'usually'.

if your resultset is numeric/float you can use the floor function

```
select floor(resultset),count(*)
 from x
   group by floor(resultset)
   order by floor(resultset)
```

Answer (score 0):

@rypress these look strikingly similar to ICD-9 Diagnosis codes for `Other respiratory tuberculosis` [ClickMe](http://www.icd9data.com/2012/Volume1/001-139/010-018/012/default.htm). Is this correct? In that case you will get Category and subcategory in your result and may change your counts`(012->012.0->012.00,012.02..)`

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempICD') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE TempICD
    END

CREATE TABLE TempICD (ICD VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO TempICD
VALUES ('012'),('012.0'),('012.00'),('012.01'),('012.02'),
      ('012.03'),('012.04'),('012.05'),('012.05'),
      ('013'),('013.0'),('013.00'),('013.01'),('013.02'),
      ('013.03'),(NULL)
```

**Query to get Category with 6 or more line items (Including Category and Sub Category):**

```
SELECT LEFT(ICD, 3) AS ICDs,
      COUNT(1) AS ICDCount
FROM TempICD
GROUP BY LEFT(ICD, 3)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
ORDER BY LEFT(ICD, 3)
```

**Query to get Category with 6 or more line items (Excluding Category and Sub Category):**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ICD, 1, CHARINDEX('.', ICD + '.') - 1) AS ICDs,
      SUM(CASE
         WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(ICD, CHARINDEX('.', ICD) + 1, LEN(ICD))) = 2 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END) AS ICDCount
FROM TempICD
WHERE ICD IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ICD, 1, CHARINDEX('.', ICD + '.') - 1)
HAVING SUM(CASE
         WHEN LEN(SUBSTRING(ICD, CHARINDEX('.', ICD) + 1, LEN(ICD))) = 2 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END) > 5
```

**Cleanup Script:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempICD') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE TempICD
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also help you.
I assume that the column is Decimal Data type.

```
SELECT  CAST([COLUMN] AS INT) [GROUP],
        COUNT(*) [COUNT]
FROM    [TABLE] T
GROUP BY CAST([COLUMN] AS INT)
```